# Plone/Zope style view overrides in Pyramid

Tags: pyramid, zope, zope.component

I have

- Add-on product defining a view ("my_view")
- Application using this addon

Both application `views.py` are scanned by configurator during the application startup.

My application needs to have a more specific version of `my_view`, as addon provided generic `my_view` doesn't know about application specific details. What would be a good Pyramid pattern do this, so that Pyramid Configurator doesn't have a conflict? Can I register a view with the same name and context more specific `IRequest` or something along the lines?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override a view it usually "just works" if the view was defined in an addon.

```
config.include('cool_addon')
config.add_view(...)
```

This works because Pyramid will see your view is closer to the top-level of the application and just has higher priority over the view defined in cool_addon. If a structure like this cannot be achieved for some reason, the brute force approach is to `config.commit()` the old configuration and then add your view afterward, at which point it will overwrite the old config.